# Rails 5.2 alternative to ActiveRecord::Migrator.up()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In my rails app I have `ActiveRecord::Migrator.up('db/views/')` and `ActiveRecord::Migrator.down('db/views/')`. After updading to rails 5.2 it seems that this function has been removed. I attempted to use `ActiveRecord::Migration.down('db/views/')` but it seems that this function does not take any parameters.

What would be the modern alternative for `ActiveRecord::Migrator.up(')`?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e17e25cd23e8abd45b1706463dd57c90fa6dcb7c/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L373 `def down` hasn't taken a parameter since ever I think, at least not in 3.2 as shown here

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I've achieved the same behaviour in an app using `ActiveRecord::MigrationContext`

```
migrations_path = 'db/views/'
if ActiveRecord.version.version >= '5.2'
  ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(migrations_path).up
else
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.up(migrations_path)
end
```

Comment: You're a delightful person, Iain Walker, wherever you are. This helped a ton. Cheers 

Comment: Nice answer, in my case I needed to run a specific migration so used this: `context.migrate(migration[:version])` for Rails 5.2